# Python mocking: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I'm writing tests for my Flask project, and are trying to mock my database model. The code looks something like this:

```
import unittest.mock

@unittest.mock.patch("server.models.user")
def test_that_response_contain_correct_user_data(self, mocked_user):
```

This results in this error message:

```
TypeError: test_that_response_contain_correct_user_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'mocked_user'
```

So it looks like the mocking framwork doesn't inject the mocked data into the function. Does anyone know what may be causing this?

Comment: Is your `test_that_response_contain_correct_user_data()` a function (not belonging to any class) or a method (part of a class)? If it is a function, the first argument `self` gets the patch object, while the second argument is not provided (so the error message). In that case, remove `self`.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I am using `@patch.object`, though.

Comment: Why is there a "self" argument in a module level function? The number of arguments need to match the number of patches applied here. If there's an enclosing class that you're not showing us, you'll need to update the example to include that detail.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to import patch from unittest.mock and use that decorator to inject the mocked data.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("server.models.user")
def test_that_response_contain_correct_user_data(self, mocked_user):
```

Comment: So, the only difference between your code and the original code is that you use the `from ... import ...` form of import. How does it change anything?

Comment: This does not work. Should be unmarked as answer.